# Objective-C switching view controllers

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am making a game and I have such view controller scheme
1(menu)--> 2 (level selection) --> 3 level (with timers etc) --->on death or win 4 finish-->again 2.
What I do
I created singleton class which keeps in array all these view controllers and I set them as rootViewControllers when needed. But I have following porblem: when I exit 3 and go to 4 I set  3 as `nil` but it seems that 3 is still working (timers are printing messages in console) and doesnt get deallocated. Maybe I dont understand something about viewcontrollers,what exactly happens when you set another as rootViewController?

Comment: I think standard practice is to load a view controller from a NIB when it's pushed on the stack--they don't normally stick around except as a special case...

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be switching `rootViewControllers` so often.  For the most part you set one controller as root for the entirety of the app.  What you should be doing is using a `UINavigationController` to manage your `UIViewControllers`.  Once you embed your program in a `UINavigationController` then all you have to do is push onto and pop off of the navigation controller's stack.  Take a look at these few methods:

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated

- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Similarly, you can add a View Controller to the stack by using a push segue (oftentimes initialized from the storyboard (if you are using one))

You can learn more about `UINavigationController` here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks alot! Btw can I pop few ViewControllers 1 by 1 without keeping references to them? Obvious ..pop,pop doesnt work

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "pop few" but if you want to pop to a specific VC then you would just loop over the UINavigationController's stack and then use `- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` to pop to the one that you want to.  This will keep popping off of the stack until it gets to the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since you have a strong reference to your view controller (in the array), it's view will be switched out, but the controller still exists, so if you have a timer started from that controller it will continue to run.  As far as the timer, I think you should invalidate it in the #3 view controller's viewDidDisappear method -- that should take care of the problem.